# How to integrate my Spring boot web app with IBM Watson Custom Visual Recognition service?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, java-ee-6

In my case,
I created a spring boot java web app with some basic functionalities, and now I need to add Watson Custom created Visual Recognition model into my web app. The process is, need to upload an image from my web app and it should be checked in the trained models in Watson VR.
Already I've GitHub project called "Max Object Detector". It also a react web app that is integrated with pre-trained models. not with custom models.
So, My question is, how to integrate my java spring boot web app with IBM Custom Visual Recognition models?

Answer (score 0):

By using the IBM-Watson SDK for Java - https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk

API Docs are available at: https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/visual-recognition/visual-recognition-v3?code=java

and

https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/visual-recognition/visual-recognition-v4?code=java